Ionic Angular: NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Pt)[Ze -> de -> de]
I am in the process of updating an Ionic 6 (Angular) project to Ionic 8  (Angular 17) and I get stuck when building the project on this error:
main.js:23 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Pt)[Ze -> de -> de]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for de!
    at Is.get (main.js:23:75445)
    at ho.get (main.js:23:84703)
    at ho.get (main.js:23:84703)
    at ot (main.js:23:73943)
    at Object.lt (main.js:23:74022)
    at ye.#e.ɵfac [as factory] (main.js:1:27503)
    at ho.hydrate (main.js:23:86100)
    at ho.get (main.js:23:84655)
    at Df.get (main.js:23:128437)
    at Yo (main.js:23:94874)
handleError @ main.js:23
main.js:1 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Pt)[Ze -> de -> de]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for de!
    at Is.get (main.js:23:75445)
    at ho.get (main.js:23:84703)
    at ho.get (main.js:23:84703)
    at ot (main.js:23:73943)
    at Object.lt (main.js:23:74022)
    at ye.#e.ɵfac [as factory] (main.js:1:27503)
    at ho.hydrate (main.js:23:86100)
    at ho.get (main.js:23:84655)
    at Df.get (main.js:23:128437)
    at Yo (main.js:23:94874)

The error doesn't tell much apart from missing provider.
This is what my app.module.ts looks like:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { browserLocalPersistence, provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import { MusicControls } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/music-controls/ngx';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { GooglePlus } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/google-plus/ngx';

import { ModalAbout } from './modals/modal-about/modal-about';
import { ModalChangePassword } from './modals/modal-change-password/modal-change-password';
import { ModalDiscovery } from './modals/modal-discovery/modal-discovery';
import { ModalFilter } from './modals/modal-filter/modal-filter';
import { ModalHistory } from './modals/modal-history/modal-history';
import { ModalLegal } from './modals/modal-legal/modal-legal';
import { ModalStreamRatings } from './modals/modal-stream-ratings/modal-stream-ratings';
import { ModalReportIssue } from './modals/modal-report-issue/modal-report-issue';
import { ModalRequestStream } from './modals/modal-request-stream/modal-request-stream'
import { PopoverRate } from './popovers/popover-rate/popover-rate';

import { CanActivateGuard } from './providers/guards/can-activate.guard';
import { SigninSignupGuard } from './providers/guards/signin-signup.guard';

import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

import { firebaseConfig } from './config/firebase.config';

export function translationLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp( () => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      auth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence);
      return auth;
    }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (translationLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: true
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalAbout,
    ModalChangePassword,
    ModalDiscovery,
    ModalFilter,
    ModalHistory,
    ModalLegal,
    ModalReportIssue,
    ModalRequestStream,
    ModalStreamRatings,
    PopoverRate
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    GooglePlus,
    HttpClient,
    MusicControls,
    Storage,
    CanActivateGuard,
    SigninSignupGuard,
    Storage
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

I have gone through all imports several times but cannot find anything wrong. Maybe I am overlooking something here?

It seems like the application is running in prod mode. Please try to reproduce the error in your development server, it will give you a proper error message with the real names of the affected injectables. If you are getting this error in your dev server, probably something is wrong with your angular.json config.

How can I serve the app in development mode, so I can see the message in the browser? Is there a command for that?

It would be helpful to share the relevant parts of angular.json. You need to make sure that for your dev server, the code is not optimized, see the docs. For newer versions of Angular, code is being optimized by default.

I've set both optimization and buildOptimizer as false in the angular.json. It doesn't have any effect.

ng serve -c development if you didn't change the angular.json should give you the un-optimized non-minified version of the build server which will give you the providers.

I'd start from provide* and move them to providers from imports. They are not modules IMO, but function returning providers. Moving to the providers array might fix the issue right away

Turns out I was missing some configuration in my angular.json file:
          "development": {
            "optimization": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false
            },

With that in place, I was able to run in development mode with the command ionic serve -c development.
Ultimately, I found the culprit. It was a missing provider for IonRouterOutlet.

Try this change. This basically moves two providers from the imports to the providers array. This might fix the issue.
Running ng serve -c development would run a local server without any optimizations/minifications of the source code. This would help narrow down the bug. Also, you can modify angular.json to use the development configuration as the default for ng serve. You can read about it here.
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (translationLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: true
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalAbout,
    ModalChangePassword,
    ModalDiscovery,
    ModalFilter,
    ModalHistory,
    ModalLegal,
    ModalReportIssue,
    ModalRequestStream,
    ModalStreamRatings,
    PopoverRate
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    GooglePlus,
    HttpClient,
    MusicControls,
    Storage,
    CanActivateGuard,
    SigninSignupGuard,
    Storage,
    provideFirebaseApp( () => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      auth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence);
      return auth;
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

